# Sum of countable Linearly independent vectors

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Is $u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}e_n$ an element of X, where $\{e_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a maximal set of linearly independent vectors in X and X is a Banach space?

In other words, are the partial sums $\sum_{n=k}^{m}\frac{1}{2^{n}}e_n$ a Cauchy sequence? If yes, then by completeness $u\in X$.

Thanks

Comment: If the system of vectors in maximal linearly independent in an infinite dimensional Banach, then it is uncountable. The sum doesn't have any chance to converge, no matter what coefficients you put.

Comment: Wait- Consider a Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis consisting of only countably many vectors. Isn't that a maximal independent system? Am I missing something?

Comment: @voldemort No. It is maximal orthogonal, but not maximal linearly independent. Orthonormal bases are not Hamel bases (not bases in the sense of basis of a vector space).

Comment: Ok. Do you have any references that give the result? I feel like you are correct, but can't place it.

Comment: @voldemort It is an easy application of Baire theorem. Banach are complete topological spaces. Consider the sets $B_n$ which are the spaces generated by the first $n$ elements of the assumed countable basis. These are nowhere dense and their union would be the whole space. That cannot happen by Baire (a complete space cannot be a countable union of nowhere dense).

Comment: Ah- right. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

This need not be true.

Consider the following vectors in $l_\infty$. $e_n=(2^n,0,...0,1,0,...)$. These vectors are certainly in $l_\infty$ and are certainly linearly independent. What happens when you try to add them up (even after normalization)?

Comment: I edited it to include your answer.

Comment: Ok- Then I should either edit my answer or delete it :)

Comment: Don't delete. The maximality condition on the set of vectors makes it even more simple to show it diverges. A maximal set of linearly independent vectors in an infinite dimensional Banach cannot be countable.